# Как правильно: был доцентом или работал доцентом?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

Речь идёт о советских временах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от конкретной ситуации. "Доцент" может обозначать как должность, так и звание. Не каждый доцент по званию занимает должность доцента (работает доцентом) и наоборот.

Не имея дополнительной информации, я бы остановился на "был".

Comment: _Не имея дополнительной информации, я бы остановился на "был"._ — не лучший выбор, если речь идёт о ещё живом человеке и о его научном звании. Я бы поостерёгся.

Answer (score 1):

**Работал доцентом** (где?) в институте (обстоятельственное значение). **Был доцентом**  кафедры/на кафедре (определительное значение).

ДОЦЕНТ, -а; м.  Учёное звание и **должность** преподавателя высшего учебного заведения; лицо, имеющее это звание и занимающее эту должность.

В приведенном примере в обоих случаях речь идет **о должности,** а не о звании, поэтому выбор зависит от наличия **обстоятельственного или определительного значения**, и это видно из примеров в Нацкорусе.

...он вернулся в Москву и вместе с областным пединститутом имени Н. К. Крупской, **где он работал доцентом,** отправился в эвакуацию в Магнитогорск. [Б. Ф. Егоров. Сын профессора и артистки // «Звезда», 2003]

В нешахматной жизни он был доцентом МГУ, кандидатом физико-математических наук.

Один из них **был доцентом** кафедры хозяйственного права.

Я в то время был доцентом кафедры астрофизики.

В Харькове отец преподавал в университете, **был доцентом** на кафедре электротерапии

Answer (score 0):

Толковый словарь Ушакова (1935-1940):
ДОЦЕ́НТ, доцента, муж. (от лат. *docens* — учащий). Ученое звание преподавателя высшего учебного заведения, ниже профессора и выше ассистента.

Толковый словарь Ожегова (1949-1992):
ДОЦЕ́НТ, -а, муж. Учёное звание преподавателя высшего учебного заведения, предшествующее профессору, а также лицо, имеющее это звание.

*Она работала доцентом, имела право на пенсию и была бездетной.*
Жорес Медведев, Нобелевские лауреаты России, 2015

*Например, по основному месту работы гражданин работает юрисконсультом, а по совместительству — доцентом в вузе.*
Е. А. Злобина, Трудовая книжка: новые правила ведения и хранения, 2009

*С 1968 по 1973 год был доцентом в Ленинградском технологическом институте целлюлозно-бумажной промышленности...

С 1973 по 1981 год — доцент, с 1982 года — профессор юридического факультета ЛГУ.*
[**А А. Собчак. Биографическая справка**](https://ria.ru/spravka/20100220/209991265.html)

Выбор глагола зависит от контекста и смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню предыдущие ответы, которые касались преимущественно должности "доцент".

В советские времена существовало также научное звание "доцент по кафедре" (затем были какие-то изменения в названии, не имеющие отношения к вопросу). Это звание присваивалось пожизненно, поэтому выражение "был доцентом" в отношении звания уместно в биографиях уже умерших людей или в некрологах. Выражение "работал доцентом" в отношении звания звучит неуместно, но в художественной литературе и, особенно, в разговорной речи употребляется.

Для ответа на вопрос нужен более широкий контекст. Идёт ли речь о художественном произведении или об официальном документе? Жив этот человек в настоящее время или нет? Также могут быть существенны другие детали.